# Control of keyboard when entering text into UITableView cells containing UITextFields

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a UITableView with custom cells containing two UITextFields for text entry. I would like the keyboard to stay in place until text entry is finished but when a second textField is tapped, the keyboard disappears and I have to make a second tap to get it back. I understand that the first tap has triggered a 'resignFirstResponder' message, but how can I keep the keyboard in place? Have tried setting the tableScrollView keyboardDissmissMode, but it makes no difference. I implement 'textFieldDidEndEditing' to store the text entered and declare the view controller to be the texField's delegate.Am using Swift 4 with iOS 12.

This is the code for the custom cell:

class ChoreoCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var inputText:String?

```
@IBOutlet weak var countText: UITextField! {
    didSet {
        countText.sizeToFit()
        countText.text = inputText
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var stepText: UITextField! {
    didSet {
        stepText.sizeToFit()
        stepText.text = inputText
    }
}
```

}

... and this is the code I am using in a tableViewController:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell( withIdentifier:Storyboard.CellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? ChoreoCell
    if (self.choreography.count == 0 ) {
        let myCountSteps = CountSteps(counts:"", steps:"" )
        for _ in 0...Storyboard.InitialRows-1 {
            self.choreography.append(myCountSteps)
        }
    }
    cell!.countText.text = self.choreography[indexPath.row].counts
    cell!.stepText.text = self.choreography[indexPath.row].steps
    cell!.countText.delegate = self
    cell!.stepText.delegate = self
    return cell!
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    guard let txt : String = textField.text else {
        print ("input error for text, editing ended but no text received")
        return
    }
    var v:UIView = textField
    repeat { v = v.superview!} while !(v is UITableViewCell)
    if let cell = v as? ChoreoCell {
        guard let ip = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
            print("Error identifying index path for \(cell)")
            return
        }            
        switch (textField) {
            case cell.countText:
                let myCountSteps = CountSteps(counts:txt, steps:cell.stepText.text! )
                self.choreography[ip.row] = myCountSteps
            case cell.stepText:
                let myCountSteps = CountSteps(counts:cell.countText.text!, steps:txt )
                self.choreography[ip.row] = myCountSteps
            default:
                print ("Unexpected textField case")
        }
        self.danceDoc?.choreography[ip.row] = self.choreography[ip.row]
        self.danceDoc?.updateChangeCount(.done)
        return
    } else {
        print ("Error identifying cell from text entry")
        return
    }
}
```

How can I determine which textField is tapped in to end the editing of the current textField, so I can assign it first responder status and prevent the keyboard disappearing?

Comment: Don't resign the current text field, make the next one become the first responder.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have similar code to this, which will cause the keyboard dismissal no matter what:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()            
    return true
}
```

To fix it - you need to programmatically activate the next Text Field:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()       
    self.nextTextField.becomeFirstResponder() // Add this line
    return true
}
```

You may need to do additional check, because for the last field you may actually need to dismiss the keyboard.

Not 100% sure if it won't affect other functionality, but I believe even `textField.resignFirstResponder()` line can be omitted (in case we want the keyboard to remain on the screen), otherwise it may cause some weird animation of the keyboard.

Comment: There is no need to call `resignFirstResponder` if you are going to call `becomeFirstResponder` on the next line.

Comment: Have tried these suggestions but still have the same problem! Also tried adding a tap action to each textField but it did not work consistently. When I tap into another box it does not recognise it as a textField, so the keyboard is dismissed.

Comment: @KJM I gave the right answer. Not sure what else is done in your code, but there may be something that leads to the weird behavior you have.

Comment: Have tried the tap actions again with this code:    @IBAction func showKeyboardOnTap(_ sender: UITextField) {
        sender.becomeFirstResponder()
    } and it seems to work, although not consistently when it doesn't recognise my taps! Many thanks for replies.